# wrap jquery when around angular data service calls within loop

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, deferred

So I have a page that upon an action needs multiple ajax calls. The angular dataService.getData is called which uses $q/deferred like so:

```
return {
    getData: function(obj) {
        var def = $q.defer();

        $http({
            url: obj.url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }).then(function(data) {
              if (data.data) {
                  def.resolve({
                     response: data 
                  })
              }
        })
        return def.promise;
    }
}
```

at one point I need to call a few individual requests on a group of items from the controller:

```
$scope.goGetEmBoys = function(group) {
    config.group.forEach(function(d) {
         if(d.name == group) {
             dataService.getData({url: d.urlToCall})
                 .then(function(data){
                       // use each with its own registered callback
                       d.callback(data);
                 })
         }
    })
}
```

What I want to do is have a bitValue to toggle when requests are working and when completed, even if I have to store something like $scope.somethingIsHappening = 0, etc

I think wrapping it in the $.when deferred reads like a reasonable approach but I have been unable to get that working, also is there a better approach to this versus trying to fit the call (goGetEmBoys function and ultimately the loop) inside a deferred like this?

tried the call to the scope function, as well as the block within it inside a jquery when....I must be using it wrong. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Choose a tag. It can't be `angularjs` **and** `angular` (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know I fully understood what do you want to achieve - you want to know when all request are completed? If length of `group` does not change, you may try the following:

```
$scope.areReqestsFinished = false;
$scope.goGetEmBoys = function(group) {
    var counter = 0;
    config.group.forEach(function(d) {
         if(d.name == group) {
             dataService.getData({url: d.urlToCall})
                 .then(function(data){
                       // use each with its own registered callback
                       d.callback(data);
                       counter++;
                       if (counter === config.group.length) {
                           $scope.areRequestFinished = true; 
                       }
                 })
         }
    })
}
```

And you can set up a `$scope.$watch` on `$scope.areRequestFinished` to act when requests are finished. You can also play with `$q.all` but I never made it working for me, also I think my solution is quite easy to figure it out, even if it requires more code. Watch can be like this:

```
$scope.$watch('areRequestFinished', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if ((newValue !== oldValue) && (newValue === true)) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```